# Using MATLAB functions in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I'm new to VB.net but I have to do this for our project. I made a very simple program to call the matlab functions that I made in vb.net. This program is simple, it will just determine the width and the height of the image in the picturebox.

Here's my matlab code and compiled it using the .NET Assembly to export a .dll files:

```
function [width, height, third] = imageInfo(input)
inImage = imread(input);
[width, height, third] = size(inImage);
end
```

Here's the GUI of my program:

[image]

And here's the vb code that I made:

```
Imports MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays
Imports MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility
Imports imageInfo

Public Class Form1
    Public myImageInfo As New imageInfoClass

    Dim imageWidth As String
    Dim imageHeight As String
    Dim result As New MWNumericArray
    Dim imagePath As String

    Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
        If ofdSelectPicture.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            pbImage.Image = Image.FromFile(ofdSelectPicture.FileName)
            imagePath = "'" & ofdSelectPicture.FileName & "'"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnProcess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProcess.Click
        result = myImageInfo.imageInfo(imagePath)
        tbHeight.Text = imageHeight
        tbWidth.Text = imageWidth
    End Sub
End Class
```

I always got an error when running the program. I hope you can help me with this one. Thank you

Comment: It would really help if you could say what type of error you're getting. Is it an exception? Does it have a message? When do you get that error?

Comment: Here's the screenshot of the error: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/819/yruy.jpg

I got the error when I'm running the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part here:

```
result = myImageInfo.imageInfo(imagePath)
```

`imagePath` needs to be the full path. You strip it out and add commas with

```
imagePath = "'" & ofdSelectPicture.FileName & "'"
```

You can try:

```
imagePath = ofdSelectPicture.SafeFileName
```

Comment: `imread` needs the full path of the file name (unless the image is in the current directory or available on the MATLAB path), but you don't have to wrap it in single quotes. The `MWArray` bridge class takes care of converting .NET strings into MATLAB strings. So I think `imagePath = ofdSelectPicture.FileName` should work..

Comment: I still get an error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Image Info.exe

Additional information: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: The type initializer for 'imageInfo.imageInfoClass' threw an exception.

Comment: @elvinguitar Do you know how to use the debugger? It would help you greatly. You can put a breakpoint on the `result = myImageInfo.imageInfo(imagePath)` line and that will make the debugger stop before the execution of that line. Then you can see the value of `imagePath`).

Comment: @MPelletier sorry but I'm new to vb.net and don't know how to use the debugger. Just want to ask, is my matlab code all correct?

Comment: For that part itself I can't say because I don't know Matlab. Sorry.

Comment: @MPelletier it's okay. Thanks anyway :)

I hope someone here will be able to help me.

Comment: Better fix your image issue first or separately. One problem per question, one question per problem :)